# How to use .so file of another android project to another project

Tags: android, android-ndk, .so

I have decompiled an android signed apk and it has a .so file...

when i am copy paste that .so file in my project's jniLibs/(abi)/*.so

The library load successfully, but it gives following error,

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.***.***.****.****.Decode:([BI[B)I
```

Here decode is native mathod.In singed apk also the are using same signature for native method...and i am also using the same method signature, then also i am getting the error like this...

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: you probably going to have legal problems by using other app's .so file. And what you are asking for is to help you with this crime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your method `com.***.***.****.****.Decode` be the `com.aaa.bbb.ccc.Ddd.Decode`. Then you should create `package` `com.aaa.bbb.ccc`, create `Ddd` `Java` `class` in this `package`, define `native` method

```
public native int Decode(byte[] in, int length, byte[] out);
```

in this `class` and add a `static` *.so library by means of:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("Ddd");
}
```

to this `class`. Make sure if your *.so file has name `libDdd.so` than you have to write just a `Ddd` in `System.loadLibrary`.

Comment: You are welcome! :) Please accept my answer if it was useful  as it is pointed here [2. Accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: can you plz ans [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874902/getting-fatal-exception-when-trying-to-play-decoded-audio-using-audiotrack]