# getting fatal exception when trying to play decoded audio using audioTrack

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-ffmpeg, android-mediacodec

I'm using `MediaCodec` for video decoding and playing it on surface texture. It all works fine, but when I am decoding audio, it's getting decoded successfully, but when I am trying to play it using `AudioTrack` I am getting following error:

```
com.**** I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.

com.**** I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.

com.**** E/ACodec: [OMX.Intel.VideoDecoder.AVC] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648

com.**** A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0029004c (code=1), thread 23469 (Audio Thread)
```

I am getting the error at this line:

```
audioTrack.write(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length);
```

Thanks in advance

@isabsent

Comment: Sorry, never had used MediaCodec. Try to search code examples by keywords on [Github](https://github.com/). This project [MediaCodecExample](https://github.com/taehwandev/MediaCodecExample) for example.

Comment: ok i will try that one...thanks for your response